# Is there a way to create a native thread for PWAs (Progressive Web Apps)? I need to access Geolocation when the browser has closed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App which needs to constantly update the users location.

Service workers are inadequate as they do not have access to the navigation.geolocation object and my current solution of using a React Component stops when closing the browser.

I have attempted  React Native Workers (https://github.com/devfd/react-native-workers) but this cannot be installed using create-react-app.

Open to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want a long-running background process you will have to create a native app.